# How to check if two users of web application belongs to same netowork/LAN/domain

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications, browser, network-programming

I have a web application with security concerns that the user should be able to login from his office network only. even if he carries his laptop outside his office he should not be able to login into an application.Also the access to application will be granted by admin user and for this the condition is the user should be under same netowork/LAN/domain as admin user.

The problem is how can I identity the user and admin are in both same network.is there any framework which can do browser communication on two different PCs in LAN or same network ? is there any way I can find network identifier of user?

Comment: This sounds like the website needs to be hosted within the company intranet, so that it can't be accessed from outside the local network.

Comment: but I want single website ..used by multiple organizations

Comment: So you want the user to login from his or her office network but _over the internet_ to your web server? Ian's suggestion makes more sense, where for use by multiple organisations they would each install your web app on their own intranets.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a set of whitelisted IP addresses which correspond to a given organization. That address represents that given network on the internet.

However, this isn't foolproof. If an attacker doesn't care about a response, (s)he can send whatever message (s)he wants and change the source IP in the sent packet. This also requires the network you want to target be on its own subnet, and that it has its own, unique, IP. It also can't handle cases where someone sets up a VPN that tunnels their internet connection through one of your whitelisted networks.

Beyond that, there's nothing you can do. Browsers don't send out personally identifying information and similar things. Anything that you could retrieve from the browser, someone could forge if they wanted to.

The only way you can be even close to sure that a site is accessible to a single network, is to host it on that network. (as comments have indicated)